# Double NAT for isolation

Tags: networking, router, home-networking, nat

I have an existing network but want to provide WiFi in a room that is isolated from my main network. I thought a simple WiFi router would be good for the job as the NAT will prevent access to anyone on WiFi to my main network.

My main network is 192.168.1.X and I have configured the second router to 10.0.0.X network and its WAN is on DHCP (on 192.168.1.200). However, while connected to second router (10.0.0.2), I can still access my main network (192.168.1.1 n so on).

Any idea how to prevent that from happening?

P.S. Searching on internet didn't help so far as 99% of results are the other way around i.e. accesing primary network behind second NAT.

P.S.(2) I know the proper way to do this is via VLANS and multiple SSIDs on APs but as you've guessed its only for guests and I need a simple inexpensive way to do that.

Comment: Setting LAN ports isolation on your main router (in your main network, with is 192.168.1.0/24 LAN) must prevent communication between them, so no interconnection between main and additional networks became possible. Of course, all another ports of your main router will be isolated too, so if you do not need it, you must use an additional commutator to connect all your main LAN nodes to your main LAN router.

Comment: With this setup you cannot reach `10.0.0.X` (inner network) from `192.168.1.Y` (outer network), not the other way around. In your case making use of this mechanism requires the router in the room to be the outer (closest to the ISP) router. Is there a DMZ option in your (current) outer router?

Comment: Many routers, even cheaper ones, have a dedicated *Guest WiFi* option, which would probably a more hassle-free way to provide access to users where there is no LAN, only WAN access.

Comment: A reminder that the 2nd NAT does nothing useful in terms of isolation. It will not prevent any access. It might hinder access to the inner network from outside, but absolutely not to the outer network from inside. The _firewall_ on the 2nd router does all of that, and it can do that without NAT.